# How to call async from sync method in blazor and wait for result?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor webassembly I have javascript function in js file:

```js
function AksMessage(message) {
    return confirm(message);
}
```

In razor file:

```cs
[Inject]
public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    
public async Task<bool> askMessage(msg)
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("AskMessage", msg);
}
```

Now in some not async function I want to call
`askMessage` and get result if user clicked and returned false or true.
How can I run it and wait for result from synchronous part of code?
If I do:

```cs
var askmsg = Task.Run(async () => await askMessage("question"));
```

and `askmsg.Result` I have exception that monitors can not wait on this runtime.

Comment: Where and why do you have non-async code?  That shouldn't be necessary. Add details to make it an answerable  question.

Comment: `AksMessage` != `AskMessage`.

Comment: [Polite] "Async All The Way" is not just a slogan, it's pretty much a rule.  Any switch from Async back into Sync can lead to deadlocks.  Go and read some of Stephen Cleary's posts over the years about DotNet async coding if you want some background.  What event/process is forcing you to switch back to sync?

Comment: I suspect that senterd is trying to call a Javascript function that is synchronous.

Comment: My use case is that I'm using a gRPC client interceptor. I can't make the methods I want to override asynchronous and one of the things I have to do in there is async (fetching a token from an identity server).

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this for setting bearer tokens on a gRPC interceptor which required some async code in WASM, you do it like this:

```cs
public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
    TRequest request,
    ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
    AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
{
    var call = continuation(request, context);

    return new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(
        call.ResponseAsync,
        GetMetadata(),
        call.GetStatus,
        call.GetTrailers,
        call.Dispose);
}

private async Task<Metadata> GetMetadata()
{
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(await _authenticationManager.TryRefreshToken()))
            _snackbar.Add("Refreshed Token.", Severity.Success);
        var token = _authenticationManager.Token;
        var metadata = new Metadata();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            metadata.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
            var userIdentity = (await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User.Identity;
            if (userIdentity!.IsAuthenticated)
                metadata.Add("User", userIdentity.Name!);
        }
        else
        {
            _authenticationManager.Logout().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }

        return metadata;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to add token to request metadata", ex);
    }
}
```

EDIT: For some reason, although this async code runs, it doesn't actually set the headers onto the request so you have to do the following hack:

```cs
public class AuthenticationInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly IAuthenticationManager _authenticationManager;
    private readonly ISnackbar _snackbar;
    private readonly NavigationManager _navigationManager;
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
    private Metadata? _metadata;

    public AuthenticationInterceptor(
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        ISnackbar snackbar,
        NavigationManager navigationManager,
        AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {
        _authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        _snackbar = snackbar;
        _navigationManager = navigationManager;
        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
    }

    public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
        AsyncUnaryCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        _ = new AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse>(
            null!,
            GetMetadata(context),
            null!,
            null!,
            null!); //  Doesn't actually send the request but runs the Task
                    // that provides the metadata to the field which can
                    // then be used to set the request headers
        
        var newOptions = context.Options.WithHeaders(_metadata!);

        var newContext = new ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse>(
            context.Method,
            context.Host,
            newOptions);
 
        return base.AsyncUnaryCall(request, newContext, continuation);
    }

    private async Task<Metadata> GetMetadata<TRequest, TResponse>(ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context)
        where TRequest : class
        where TResponse : class
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(await _authenticationManager.TryRefreshToken()))
                _snackbar.Add("Refreshed Token.", Severity.Success);
            var token = _authenticationManager.Token;
            Console.WriteLine($"Token: {token}");
            var headers = new Metadata();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                headers.Add(new Metadata.Entry("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}"));
                Console.WriteLine("Set metadata");
                var userIdentity = (await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync()).User.Identity;
                if (userIdentity!.IsAuthenticated)
                    headers.Add(new Metadata.Entry("User", userIdentity.Name!));
            }
            else
            {
                await _authenticationManager.Logout();
                _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
            }
            
            var callOptions = context.Options.WithHeaders(headers);
                
            return _metadata = callOptions.Headers!;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to add token to request headers", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can call async method from synchronous method and wait for it like this :

```
var askmsg = Task.Run(async () => await askMessage("question"));
var result = Task.WaitAndUnwrapException();
```

another solution is like this (sync method backs to its context):

```
var result = AsyncContext.RunTask(askMessage("question")).Result;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The question is regarding running inside of Blazor, where the threading model is significantly different than normal .Net. Task.WaitAndUnwrapException(); and AsyncContext.RunTask() aren't valid C#. Unlike normal .Net, Blazor (running inside of WebAssembly) is single threaded. If you try to block a thread to wait for a task to complete, you will get a runtime exception.

Comment: Agree, this solution does not work. Doing anything like `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` throws.